# Column freeze in GridView

Tags: c#, css, gridview, asp.net-4.0

I have a asp .net web application where I use GridView. There is whole lot of data in it, making it to scroll horizontal as well as vertical. Now, I wanted to freeze the first column in it while horizontal scroll is happening. I got some help from the forums online and wrote this particular piece of css style:

```
td.locked, th.locked
{
    position: relative;
    top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
    background-color: White;        
}
```

and in the code behind I have this in my grid's RowDataBound event:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "locked";
```

But now, freezing of the columns happens in a and if say I have 15 records and my div shows only 10 records and rest has to go for vertical scroll, but the frozen column's 15 rows are overflowing the grid. Please find the screenshot below:
[image: sample screenshot]

Please let me know what have I missed out so that I could enable vertical scroll for overflown data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try my solution. It can be fixed header and column in gridview.

[GridViewScroll with jQuery](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/)

https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll

[image]

Comment: It really looks like an amazing job, I guess you spent a lot of time in this, I am sorry it did not work in my case, I tried with a normal gridview with columns already generated, nothing special, I tried with jquery 3.3.1 and jquery-ui 12.1 but no luck, no error reported no nothing, it just didn't do anything but many thanks for your work, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you set height and width for the gridview ? try to set height and width for it and set its wrapper's height and width.
hope can help you.

Comment: its actually part of an existing application, so i've to keep the width and height the same... is there any workaround from the style side?