# Why GridView.Columns[number].frozen does not support?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using visual studion 2008 and .NET framework 3.5 SP1.

I want to freeze a column From a Dynamic GridView.

```
<div id="divGrid">     
      <asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" >
      </asp:GridView>
```

I found many solution like

```
grdData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
grdData.DataBind();  
divGrid.Columns[1].Frozen = true;
```

It was supposed to freeze my column No 1. But i don't know why `divGrid.Columns[1].Frozen`
is not supporting here. Can anyone Help me? Thanks in advance for your Help

Comment: Check if this helps : [Stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14494040/3185569

Comment: thanks for comment.But that doesn't works

Comment: There is no property called `Frozen` in the `DataControlField` class